# How To covert mp4 video to m3u8 in ffmpeg using nodejs

Tags: node.js, ffmpeg

I am able to change the resolution of the video but I am getting error while trying to convert it to m3u8 format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

m3u8 format is not contains any video data, it just a text file of playlist someone gives a question like this from [Quora](https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-convert-an-MP4-to-an-M3U8-file-format)

If you want to change the resolution of video by `ffmpeg`, you can read document of [scale](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Scaling)

for example: `ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vf scale=320:240 output.mp4`